# How do I make a bootable OS or make an app that can be bootable on Mac?

Tags: macos, operating-system, realbasic, xojo

I made a desktop application that looks like an OS. My question is, can I have that app and make it boot up when I start my Mac just like how OS X would start> If I can, then how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Uuuugh, what? I don't think you made an OS... But perhaps you made some sort of useful management software, a "Launcher" or similar... There used to be something in Classic OS days that would run without the finder, and allowed you to launch apps. If you wanted to do something similar, I guess you would need to figure out which launchd plist is starting the Finder, and unload it early during boot, and figure out how to get yours launched.

Comment: hmm I don't exactly understand, you know how when someone installs windows on a mac? and then when they restart and holt the option key it lets them chose to start in os x or windows, I want that but with my program

Comment: that is using boot camp... it would be easier to develop an os on a VM now of course... I don't really know how you would build an OS in a framework like xojo.. you have to write lots of very low level stuff to deal with processor signals and memory management etc...

Comment: You can write an OS in whatever you like: https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/nodeos-the-javascript-based-operating-system

Answer (score 1):

Since you made an app, it needs the OS to start it. With OS X, you can use [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) to set that up.

Comment: Could you tell me how exactly I would set it up with launchd? I have searched it up but I didn't find anything. I am also very new to this

Comment: My answer has a link to the launchd man page. I have not used it myself, but I'm sure you can find answer here on StackOverflow. If not, start a new question.